# Is it possible to hide the application tile of a metro app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to hide a live tile of a metro app?. After the metro app is installed in a machine the tile for the app is displayed in the start screen by default. Is it possible to not display the tile of the app programatically. My requirement is the user should be able to open the app through some thing like custom URL scheme not by clicking on the tile. The app is not going to be submitted to the windows store. It is for internal use only. So I dont need to worry about if there are any hacked ways to do this.

Comment: It would still show up in the "all apps" listing though.  You probably want to capture the activation mechanism in code and throw up a message saying the app can't be run in this mode.  That said, I do see that 'hiding' the tile would eliminate a lot (but not all) of the invalid activations.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you wanted but anyway:

1. Go to your Package.appxmanifest.
2. Under Declarations select Protocol and press Add.
3. Choose a Name for your app and save the changes.
4. You can now open "Run" and type in the name and ":test" and the app will open.